# What kind of effects does mantra japa have on our bodies?

Tags: mantras, siddhi, japa

What are  the siddhis one gets by performing the japa of the Mantras of different deities with different sadhanas, 1008 times or more?

What kind of effects will happen to our body after certain number of chantings of a particular Mantra?

if I chant the Bijakshara (single lettered mantra) of any deity for 1 lakh times, will I experience some changes in my body?

Will I get will-power, attraction etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word mantra in Sanskrit means ‘that which protects by being meditated upon’ (***mananAt trAyate iti mantrah***).

Mantra can contain bijAksharAs and  name of the deity.

> Example: chAmundA mantra ॐ ऐं ह्रीं क्लीं चामुण्डायै विच्चे।
>
> Ganapati mantra : ॐ Gam Ganapataye Namaha

or may contain words like gAyatri mantra:

> ॐ भूर् भुवः स्वः ।
> तत्स॑वि॒तुर्वरेण्यं॒
> भर्गो॑ दे॒वस्य॑धीमहि ।
> धियो॒ यो नः॑ प्रचो॒दया॑त् ॥

---

Coming to the question part, the OP asked about the effects/Siddhis/changes after reciting a mantra for certain times on daily basis.

It is a very tricky question indeed.

---

One must understand that the purpose of mantra,ie., daily recitation of particular words/sounds for certain times  or meditation on a image, etc, is to train the mind to hang on to a **single idea**, but not to attain powers/siddhis or concentration, etc.  One has to discard that **single idea** finally to attain ABSOLUTE BLISS.

Attaining powers/siddhis or concentration, etc, may  occur as a consequence of doing mantra japa or meditation on a form, etc.

In the case of some persons, mantra japa or meditation on a form, etc, may result only in ABSOLUTE BLISS but not in attaining powers.

**It depends on one's prArabdha (stored merit of the body).**

---

Any mantra should be learnt from an accomplished person in a particular mantra, otherwise  recitation of a mantra will be equal to a nAma japa (recitation of sacred name like Sri Raama) only, but not a mantra japa.

A small but a vital hitch is to be noted here.

**An accomplished person in a particular mantra will never reveal the secret of recitation to every person, but wait for a person who has reached certain maturity levels.**

If a matured disciple is available, the accomplished guru will catch hold of him and teach it to him.

To understand this concept, please read Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa and Swami Vivekananda life histories. **Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa imparted his knowledge completely to Swami Vivekananda only.**

---

Consider the case of Sri Kaavyakantha Ganapati Muni, a disciple of Sri Ramana Maharshi.

A great scholar, a performer of varieties of mantra japa, yet remained unsatisfied due to non-realisation of all his actions, till he met Sri Ramana Maharshi.  Consider his own words when he met Sri Ramana Maharshi.

http://kavyakantha.arunachala.org/KNatesan.htm

**"All that has to be read I have read. Even Vedanta Sastra I have fully understood. I have performed japa to my heart's content, yet I have not up to this time understood what tapas is. Hence, have I sought refuge at thy feet. Pray enlighten me about the nature of tapas."**

---

A Guru's guidance is **sine qua non** in mantra's recitation, which results in BLISS.